# Detect IE11 in Angular 5 and suppress "property doesn't exist" warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular5

I'm working on custom directive which requires scroll position. I found all major browsers support `window.scrollY` while IE11 needs `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

so I'm trying to determine if current browser is IE11 here:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;// tslint:disable-line
    this.checkScrollPosition();
  }
```

where I'm getting ts errors `property MSInputMethodContext doesnt exist on type Window` and `property documentMode doesnt exist on type Document`, though the code works fine in all browsers where I tested (chorme, safari, ie11)

1) am I right thinking this will work fine since TS will be translated to the pure JS where these properties will be accessible?

2) should I suppress this warning (how?) or should I try different browser detection approach?

I tried adding this, but no luck as of now:

```
//tslint:disable-line
//noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedProperty
```

Comment: Note: detecting IE11 might still be useful in your code, but in the part where you want to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead of `window.scrollY`, maybe it's a better idea to test the existence of this specific property than to rely on others. Seems safer to me. To prevent the error, maybe you can use `'scrollY' in window`?

Comment: It looks like you can use `pageYOffset` instead of `scrollY`. `pageYOffset` is an alias of `scrollY` but has better support : https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use `pageYOffset` instead of `scrollY`. `pageYOffset` is an alias of `scrollY` but has better support : https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset

If you want to persist with your solution :

1) yes, you are right to assume that.

2) You can suppress the warning with a simple dummy cast:

`!!(window as any).MSInputMethodContext && !!(document as any).documentMode;`

Comment: thanks, pageYOffset works like a charm, thank's for suggestion!